# Update from Inner join syntax

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

It seems I dont have my syntax quite right for this and have tried a few different ways of writing it, what am I doing wrong?

```
UPDATE `allranks`
SET `allranks`.`Ranktwo` = `therankings`.`Rank`
FROM `allranks`
INNER JOIN `therankings`
ON (`therankings`.`Player Name` = `allranks`.`Player Name`)
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct MySQL syntax is:

```
UPDATE allranks ar INNER JOIN
       therankings r
       on ar.`Player Name` = r.`Player Name`
    SET ar.Ranktwo = r.Rank;
```

Notice how the table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.